# System environment variable as login within domain?

Tags: java, windows, security, authentication, environment-variables

I was wondering if the following scenario is secure:

- Users log into a domain "xxx.com"
- Each user has a unique login name "abcdef@xxx.com", managed in a Windows Active directory

Following java code for login:

```
String login = System.getProperty("user.name"); //windows username environment variable
User user_loggedin = UserDAO.findMyLogin(login); // find the information/permissions for the username
```

The java web application would be hosted on a server that's only accessible within the domain. Is this a secure enough login check, or could this be easily circumvented?

Comment: That depends.  Is that code fragment running on a server, or on the clients desktop?

Comment: The code fragment would be a web application running on a server, with the user not having any permissions on the server

Comment: In that case, if it works at all, it should be reasonably secure - but you should check the vendor's documentation for whichever web server (and other relevant components) you're using.